# Connestions ActivityStreamService getActivityStream throws NullPointerException.

Tags: connection, ibm-sbt

I try to access my activity stream. I'm already authenticated

```
Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
header.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
ActivityStreamService svc = new ActivityStreamService("GIConnections");
this.list = svc.getActivityStream("@me", "@all", "@all", header);
```

But the list is empty. I debug it deep in the SDK it found the place:

```
com.ibm.sbt.util.DataNavigator$Json._extractChildren
```

The JsonFactory is asked if the prop is an array. But prop is null and JsonFactory throws a NullPointerException

```
} else if(factory.isArray(prop)) {
```

The requested property was "attachments" and my activity stream entry has no attachments. :-(
I added an entry with an attachment and now it throws the same error as the image of the attachment.

What is wrong? I cannot believe that the SDK throws errors on so simple situations.

Thx
Andreas

Comment: have you tried going to the base URL and seeing if you have any data in the array?  such as https://YOURHOSTNAME:PORTNUM/connections/opensocial/basic/rest/activitystreams/@me/@all/@all

Comment: I debuged it and a saw a Json structure with a current activity entry. But this does not contains a element "attachments" and therefore prop is null and isArray() throws NullPointerException.

Comment: The errors occurs in the SDK version of April. I install today the version of July and there it throws no error. Thx Paul

Comment: Andreas - Phil Riand fixed this issue in one of the most recent builds. https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/commits/master/src/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.sbt.core/src/com/ibm/sbt/util/DataNavigator.java  <- You can see the history by clicking it on the History Tab.   I do a quick search of github to see  *per Vimal's answer below.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it on latest OpenNtf build. A fix for this issue has already been delivered. 
Link to download latest build : http://ibmsbt.openntf.org/